# Remove shadow from standard marker in leaflet maps?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Is it possible to remove shadow from standard marker in [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) maps?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In source code `new L.Icon.Default()` is used:
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/marker/Marker.js#L10

So, it can be achieved following way:

```
var icon = new L.Icon.Default();
icon.options.shadowSize = [0,0];
var marker = new L.Marker(map.getCenter(), {icon : icon}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Doesn't work any more with Leaflet 0.7.7? It always tries to load *images/marker-shadow.png*.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want a simpler, more lightweight icon, try using [divIcon](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#divicon):

```
var myIcon = L.divIcon({className: 'my-div-icon'});
// you can set .my-div-icon styles in CSS

L.marker([50.505, 30.57], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);
```